# How to use SCSS to make a class that contains bootstrap classes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

My problem is that I have several DIVs that all look like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
  ...
```

The thing is, if I decide to change the layout of this, I want to change all of them at once. I tried doing this:

CSS:

```
.product-layout {
  @extend .col-sm-4;
  @extend .col-md-3;
  @extend .col-lg-2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="product-layout">
  ...
```

But this didn't work. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

In order to be able to use extend, you should also make sure that you use `@import` to include bootstrap in your project.
(cfr. http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5)

so basically you would use `@import "bootstrap";` (using the bootstrap sass project: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass).

If bootstrap isn't included in your scss, you won't be able to extend the classes.

---

example:

```
/* Import bootstrap-sass so that we have access to all of its selectors */
@import "bootstrap";

.product-layout {
    @extend .col-sm-4;
    @extend .col-md-3;
    @extend .col-lg-2;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap is definitely included before my SCSS file.

Comment: included before the scss file is not enough (if you mean included in the html with a different <link> tag). It should be imported in the file. Otherwise you don't have access to the selectors.

Comment: If the `bootstrap.css` file is already included, will importing it in my SCSS file cause any problems?

Comment: i don't think it will cause problems, but it will cause a lot of unnecessary duplicated code. Since you're basically including bootstrap twice.